# AttributeError: module 'BRMapp.models' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django, django-models

AttributeError: module 'BRMapp.models' has no attribute 'objects'

Please refer to the below image :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0gG0.jpg

showing error:
`books = models.objects.all() AttributeError: module 'BRMapp.models' has no attribute 'objects'`

Comment: It is not `models.objects.all()`. You need to select a model, for example `Book.objects.all()`, you wrote somewhere `books = models.objects.all()`. That being said, it looks like there are a lot of anti-patterns in your views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks Man . It's working now :)